Navigating between articles in detail view with dynamically loaded data
I'm building a SwiftUI app that displays a list of articles fetched from Firestore. The app has a list view that shows the articles and a detail view that presents the detailed information of a selected article. The articles are loaded dynamically in batches in the list view.
I tried to adapt some examples of todo lists from swiftful thinking with MVVM architecture: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwvDm4VfkdpheGqemblOIA7v3oq0MS30i
And some examples from Peterfriese to create a todo list with firestore:
https://peterfriese.dev/blog/2020/replicating-reminder-swiftui-firebase-part1/
However those examples estimate that there are only a few todo items and there is no option to switch between them in detailview - you always go back to list view and then click on the next item to go back to detail view.
With my kind of RSS-reader I need to read hundreds of articles quickly - so in order not to exceed my firestore read limits I need dynamic loading of the list as there can be thousands of articles in my firestore db and I dont want to load them all on startup.
But then I need to skip through all articles that match certain filter criteria i have set up in the list view in detail view as well.
The current implementation works fine for displaying the list of articles and navigating to the detail view. However, I'm facing an issue when trying to navigate to the next or previous article in the detail view.
Here's a simplified version of the relevant code:
swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentIndex = 0
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: FirestoreDataViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(Array(viewModel.items.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { index, item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(currentIndex: $currentIndex, items: viewModel.items)) {
                        ArticleRow(item: item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var currentIndex: Int
    let items: [Article]
    
    var body: some View {
        // Display the detailed information of the article at the current index
        // Allow navigation to the next or previous article
    }
}

The issue arises because the currentIndex in the detail view is not updated correctly when navigating to the next or previous article. The currentIndex in the list view represents the index of the first item in the currently loaded batch of articles, while the detail view needs to access articles beyond the initially loaded batch.
I'm seeking advice on the best approach to handle this situation and enable smooth navigation between articles in the detail view.
What is the recommended way to access individual articles in the detail view when the articles are loaded dynamically in batches in the list view?
Should I modify the architecture of the app to better accommodate this functionality? If so, what changes would you suggest?
How can I ensure that the currentIndex in the detail view stays in sync with the actual index of the displayed article, even when navigating beyond the initially loaded batch?

Navigation view doesn’t sound like the right tool for this.

I would suggest ditch the view model and use .task(id:) to download the data where the id is an index or article ID. Saving it in a model object or simply in @State is up to you.

As I understand your goal is to get the next and prev article of current article in DetailView, I suggest you could have a function to get next article base on current list and item itself, not rely on currentIndex:
struct Article: Identifiable {
    var id: String = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentArticle: Article? = nil
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: FirestoreDataViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(Array(viewModel.items.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { index, item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(currentArticle: currentArticle, article: item)) {
                        ArticleRow(item: item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Observable
class FirestoreDataViewModel {
    var list: [Article] = []
    
    func getNextArticle(article: Article) -> Article? {
        guard let index = list.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == article.id }),
              index + 1 < list.count
        else { return nil }
        return list[index + 1]
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var currentArticle: Article?
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: FirestoreDataViewModel
    
    let article: Article
    
    var body: some View {
        // Display the detailed information of the article at the current index
        // Allow navigation to the next or previous article
        Button(action: {
            currentArticle = viewModel.getNextArticle(article: article)
        }, label: {
            Text("Go Next")
        })
    }
}

